# What is the difference between TensorFlow's contrib.slim.nets and models/slim/nets?

Tags: tensorflow

In Github repository, we have tensorflow/models having [slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim) and we also have slim in [tensorflow.contrib.slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim)

They both have similar names, functionality and structure. They provide similar nets. For example, inception_v1

- any reference for this brain split?
- why they did not just git sub
  module? any discussion link?
- which is the most usable/stable/maintained?
- which is the real net used to train pre-trained data? [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_v3.py) or [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v3.py)

which one of those two is the real slim shady?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb under the section titled *Installation and setup* :

> Since the stable release of TF 1.0, the latest version of slim has been available as tf.contrib.slim, although, to use TF-Slim for image classification (as we do in this notebook), you also have to install the TF-Slim image models library from here.

Comment: Link is broken.